# Can you use git describe to differentiate between a release, a hotfix and a feature?

Tags: git, powershell, github

I have an application that I'm using PowerShell to build. I want to upload the build files automatically to AWS s3. I want to make the folder structure to look like this:

```
Releases > v3.0.0
           v3.0.1
           v3.1.0
           v4.0.0

Features > <insert git description here>
           v3.0.0-1-g324954
           v3.0.0-2-g453634

Hotfixes > v3.0.1-1-g3242345
```

In this scenario, I am trying to organize the s3 buckets. Currently, I'm using 'git describe' and comparing it to 'git describe --abbrev=0' to see if it has a hash or not. If it doesn't have a hash, I assume it is a release and put it in that folder. I'm not sure how to determine if it is a feature or a hotfix after that.

Is what I'm trying to achieve reasonable or even possible?

Comment: You have a tool (like a screwdriver, sort of: "git describe") and a problem to solve ("build a box"). You're asking if this one tool will get the whole job done. No, it won't. Could it be *useful* in getting the job done? Sure: if the box goes together *with* screws, the screwdriver will be helpful (under the right conditions: phillips vs slot, etc). But if the box goes together with rivets, or with dovetail joints and glue, no. You're starting from the wrong end here: you want to attack the "build a box" problem, not the "use a screwdriver" one.

Comment: Ultimately, I think the right way to go about this is to forget about "git describe", at least up front: have some other way to tell these things apart, such as a "release version" file or string somewhere. Then *maybe* introduce "git describe" later to compare the result of describe, and its tag if any, to the version string: if "describe" says it's v3.0.1-<something>, and it internally says it's 3.0.1, it's obviously not 3.0.1 itself, so maybe it's a fix to 3..0.1.

Comment: Whether and when to rely on the automated tool *after* defining the whole framework, or as part of *putting together* the whole framework, is a useful question, but you'll definitely need some exterior framework.